# DataTemplateSelector won´t get used

Tags: wpf, templates, listview, datatemplate, datatemplateselector

To switch between two `ItemTemplates` in my `ListView` based on the current Item type, I implemented a `DataTemplateSelector`. I added it via `Binding` to the `ListView`. But if I set a breakpoint, it never gets called. I tried everything, nothing works.

```
public class ListViewTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate SectionTemplate { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate EntryTemplate { get; set; }

    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        if (item is Section)
        {
            return SectionTemplate;
        }

        if (item is Entry)
        {
            return EntryTemplate;
        }

        return base.SelectTemplate(item, container);
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<ListView DataContext="{Binding ElementName=This}" x:Name="list" Margin="200,25,0,0" ItemsSource="{Binding CurrentSelection}" ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource TemplateSelector}">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="ID" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ID}" Width="100" />
            <GridViewColumn Header="Value" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Value}" Width="300" />
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>

<DataTemplate x:Key="sectionTemplate">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Image Width="16" Height="16" Source="\Icons\blue-folder.png" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ID}" Margin="5,0,0,0" />
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate x:Key="entryTemplate">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Image Width="16" Height="16" Source="\Icons\ui-text-field-medium.png" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ID}" Margin="5,0,0,0" />
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>

<sdk:ListViewTemplateSelector x:Key="TemplateSelector" SectionTemplate="{StaticResource sectionTemplate}" EntryTemplate="{StaticResource entryTemplate}" />
```

Has anybody an idea how to fix that?

Thanks R

Comment: Are you seeing any items at all? Are there any binding errors in the output window?

Comment: All items are visible. The list is filled as expected. But I want some Icons in the first column dependending on the item-type. And no, there are no binding-issues... It just don´t uses the selector...

Comment: I guess you would have to use the GridViewColumn's [`CellTemplateSelector`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.gridviewcolumn.celltemplateselector.aspx) instead of the ListView's `ItemTemplateSelector`.

Comment: Maybe, but shouldn´t work ListView's selector? For what reason do I have to use GridView to use a selector? ... It doesn´t make sense to me :-/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [GridView Overview > GridView Layout and Style](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752213.aspx#GridViewLayoutandStyle) > Defining and Styling Columns in a GridView:

> When defining the data field to display in a GridViewColumn, use the
>   DisplayMemberBinding, CellTemplate, or CellTemplateSelector
>   properties. The DisplayMemberBinding property takes precedence over
>   either of the template properties.

Hence you would have to remove the `DisplayMemberBinding` from your GridViewColumns and set the [`CellTemplateSelector`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.gridviewcolumn.celltemplateselector.aspx) instead of the ListView's `ItemTemplateSelector`:

```
<GridView>
    <GridViewColumn Header="ID" Width="100"
                    CellTemplateSelector="{StaticResource TemplateSelector}"/>
    <GridViewColumn Header="Value" Width="300"
                    DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Value}"/>
</GridView>
```

Comment: Thanks, that fixed the problem! It makes sense. Now my ListView shows the correct icons in front of the cells :)